# How to add a triangle symbol on the top of the vertical line in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I add a triangle symbol on top of the red line `axvline`?

input

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: '2020-01-01 06:00:00', 
                    1: '2020-01-01 18:00:00', 
                    2: '2020-01-02 06:00:00',
                    3: '2020-01-02 18:00:00',
                    4: '2020-01-03 06:00:00',
                    5: '2020-01-03 18:00:00',
                    6: '2020-01-04 06:00:00',
                    7: '2020-01-04 18:00:00'},
              'B': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3:6, 4:7, 5:7, 6:1, 7:1}})
```

Code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.bar(df['A'], df['B'], linestyle='-',color='midnightblue' ,lw=6, width=0.01)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.axvline('2020-01-02 18:00:00', color='red', zorder=1, linestyle='--')
```

Comment: Thank you. But I do not want to add the symbol. Instead, I want to turn the line ending into triangle.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a dedicated arrow function? `ax.arrow()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.bar(df['A'], df['B'], linestyle='-',color='midnightblue' ,lw=6, width=0.01)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

# ax.axvline('2020-01-02 18:00:00', color='red', zorder=1, linestyle='--')
ax.arrow(3,0,0,df['B'].max(), head_width=0.1, head_length=0.3, fc='r', ec='r', linestyle=':')
ax.set_ylim(0,df['B'].max()+0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to add the triangle to the line at `'2020-01-02 18:00:00'`

Comment: If you fix it with `ax.arrow(3,....) `and we've updated the code and graph.

Comment: I see you are using index `3` instead of the date. Is it possible to use the date?

Comment: You can do it with dates. Your challenge has produced good results. Now it's just a matter of which one looks better.